# css cache see if file is latest or cached

Tags: css, google-chrome, caching

I would like to see if a CSS file is a cached version or just pulled down from  the server. Is there anyway in chrome (or any other browser for that matter) for me to see the date and time the css file was retrieved from the server?

Please note I'm not try to do "cache busting", force refreshing or anything. I simply want to see the age of the css / js files etc.

thanks!

Comment: is the `Network` tab of Dev Tools not sufficient? You could view `Time` and `Initiator` values for each CSS file.

Comment: Thanks @AkinHwan, that'll tell me if it's from cache (using "Size" column, but not when the cached items were downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Akin above, that helped me find it.

**If Cached or Downloaded**

Dev Tools > Network tab > Size Column will tell if it's from Cache or downloaded.

**To get the date when Cached Item was downloaded**

Dev Tools > Network tab, then right click on the column headers.
Click on Response Headers then "Manage Header Columns". Create a new one called "Date", then add that as a column.